# MS Excel - How to select a radioButton when click on cell not on the radioButton itself

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on some sort of survey for a client. He sent me an example where you can select a radiobutton by clicking on the cell that contains the radiobutton, I mean, you don´t have to click specifically on the radiobutton itself to activate it.

As I said, in the example that I got (which is locked so I can´t see how was done) I click the cell, the radio get activated, BUT in the file that I´m working I have to click exactly in the radiobutton to get it selected.

Any ideas on how to make it like the example I mentioned?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: when you create your radio button, just expand the size of the radio control to fill the whole cell it is in

Comment: @datatoo: please put your comment in an answer. After that, elunicotomas can accept it, which closes this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your radio button, just expand the size of the radio control to fill the whole cell it is in